# unable to read .mp4 from opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv

The following is the code used to read the `.mp4` video from python. The code `cap.isOpened()` is returning false.

FYI:
I installed the relavant codes and copied `opencv_ffmpeg_64.dll` into python folder (/usr/local/lib/python2.7)

-Opencv version: 3.0

-Python:2.7

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import gtk
import pygtk
import gobject

count=0
loop=0
cascPath = 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('sample.mp4')

print (cap.isOpened())
```

Please suggest what best can be done?

Comment: Have you tried running the `.open()` method? `cap.open()`

Comment: is `sample.mp4` file in the same directory as that of your Python script ?

Comment: its in same same directory and tried with cap.open() as well

Answer (score 1):

You're probably missing FFMPEG. OpenCV needs the codec information to decode the videos, which ffmpeg provides.

Download FFMPEG from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ by hitting the 'Download FFmpeg' button. Ensure you have selected the correct version, architecture and 'Statis' build. 
Unzip the downloaded file, rename it as 'ffmpeg' and move to C:\ (for eg). Now add the path C:\ffmpeg\bin to your PATH system variable.

The steps are detailed here with pictures: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-FFmpeg-on-Windows

Comment: I am using ubuntu (in VM machine), inspite all the above configurations same issue is persisting.

Comment: Inspite of installing ffmpeg https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer  on ubuntu but didn't work......

Comment: Could you try this piece of code to ensure cv2 works:
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "begin"
    img = np.zeros((300, 300))
    cv2.imshow("tet", img)
    if cv2.waitKey():
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()`
Also, did you install opencv  through Anaconda or pip?

Comment: @AvinaashGollapudi Were you able to fix the issue?